Connectiontimeout vs Connection Refused
Scenaio:
We ran some tests where one api is down, we fire requests to this api which is down from another api, majority of the Requests have connection Refused exception, wheras very few have connectionTimeoutException, any know why this is happening, threadpool size is 500.
Both the apis are inside kube cluster.
TIA
I am expecting all to be connection refused, but found some were connection timeout.

Besides some generalities as provided by Kiran's answer below, this question cannot really be answered without more detail.

Yes, you are right @Tijmen, I also faced these similar issues based on my observations provided below information as an answer.

Please find the below basic differences between Connection Timeout and Connection Refused:
Connection Timeout:

Indicates that the connection to a container took longer than established time.

It occurs when pod or service not responding or is slow to respond.

It can be caused by network congestion, high latency, or pod/service being overwhelmed with requests.


Connection Refused:

indicates that connection to a server or container was actively refused.

It occurs when a pod or service is not running, or the target port is not exposed.

It can be caused by pod/service being down, network policies blocking the connection or incorrect port configurations.


If you want to receive only Connection Refused errors, try implementing the below client side optimizations techniques to avoid connection timeouts:

Try Implementing a retry mechanism with backoff in your API code, which allows you to try connecting again after a delay, which may help to improve the chances of reaching the server during a transient network issue. Refer to an Open github issue for more information.

As per your requirement, fine tune the connection timeout settings in your API code,  which may help to increase the chances of catching transient network issues, but it can also increase the time it takes to detect that the server is down.


You can run the kubectl network commands (kubectl exec -it <pod-name\> -- bash) inside the pod hosting your second API. Analyze network connectivity to the down API using tools like Ping, Telnet, and Curl. Also refer to the Kubernetes Pod Networking: A Practical Guide,which is published on Overcast blog by DavidW (skyDragon) for more information.

Did you just copy/paste Kiran's answer? Not cool bro.

@Tijmen, We all are part of the support team and Hemanth did not copied my answer.
